# Searching the DOM on click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

Say I have the following code:

```
$('.some-class a').click(function() {
    // Do something
});
```

Will JQuery search the DOM each time `.some-class a` is clicked? Or will the DOM be searched just once? I'm wondering if it will improve performance if I make `$('.some-class a')` a variable and change it to:

```
var $someClass = $('.some-class a');
$someClass.click(function() {
    // Do something
});
```

Comment: It will be searched once in both of the snippets. The only advantage to the second snippet is if you're re-using the `$someClass` variable. In other words, it will be queried each time you use `$('.some-class a')`, but since you're only querying once, both snippets are the same. Use a variable if you need to cache/store the jQuery object.

Comment: I knew it helped if I re-use it, but wasn't sure about using it just once. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case :

```
$('.some-class a').click(function() {
    // Do something
});
```

This instruction will be executed once : jQuery will search the DOM once, find requested elements and attach click events to them. The end.

In this case :

```
function hideStuff(){
    $('.some-class a').hide()
}
```

jQuery will have to search the DOM every time the function is called.
In order to avoid that, store the objects in a variable (it's called caching) :

```
var $elems = $('.some-class a')

function hideStuff(){
    $elems.hide()
}
```

Every time the `hideStuff()` function is called, jQuery won't have to search the DOM, it's already got all the elements stored in memory, so it's much faster.

Answer (score 0):

it will bind the event to the selector once

if you want it for example to search for anchor everytime u click u could do :

```
 $('.some-class').on('click','a',function(){  /**/  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are to worried about the performance, maybe you can do it with native JS

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.some-class a'), function (element) {
  element.addEventListener('click', function() {
      alert('clicked');
  }, false);
});
```

Just need to be aware that queryselectorall is not supported by IE8 http://caniuse.com/#search=queryselectorall